# How to remove decimal points in SQL when you create a View

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
(IsNUll((CAST(MHSE_ as varchar (20))),'')  + ' ' + isnull(MDIRCT,'') + ' ' +  IsNull(MSTRT,'') + ' ' + isnull(MSTTYP,'')) as FULLADDRESS
```

This is in View trying to combine multiple column in one 
MHSE_ column has decimal.

My result now comes like:

```
13185.00000000 Dawn blvd
```

I want to result to come

```
13185 Dawn blvd
```

Note:

```
MHSE_ = house number 
MDIRECT = Apt A B etc 
MSTRT = street name 
MSTTYP = if its Road or Drive etc`
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please edit your post and select the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast and replace

```
select REPLACE( cast( MHSE_ column AS CHAR), '.','') from your_view
```

and eventually trim of the zero

and in you case

```
(IsNUll(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM (REPLACE( cast( MHSE_ column AS CHAR), '.',''))),''))
```

with floor

```
,(IsNUll((Cast(FLOOR(MHSE_) as CHAR (20))),'')  +
 ' ' + isnull(MDIRCT,'') + ' ' +  IsNull(MSTRT,'') + ' ' + 
        isnull(MSTTYP,'')) as FULLADDRESS
```

Comment: the table belongs to customer i'm not allowed to alter the table. is there a way that i can change it in View

Comment: The same instruction work non a view ... because work on a column .. i have update the answer

Comment: can you write the whole code as it should be in View. cause i tried to replace varchar with CHAR still it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to convert a number to a character string **in Oracle** (please select the proper tag for your database!) is the function `to_char()` with an appropriate format model, for example '999999' or, better, 'TM9' (which returns the number in the form that uses the fewest characters possible).

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34570

For example:

```
SQL> select to_char(13185, 'TM9') from dual;

TO_CHAR(13185,'TM9')
----------------------------------------------------------------
13185
```

In your view definition, just write `to_char(MHSE_, 'TM9')` instead of your `CAST` expression.

If you have a say in it (you may not, you indicated the table belongs to your customer) - house numbers should not be stored in number format, but in varchar2 format. How are you going to store house number 33A in a number field?

Good luck!